# I would like to use simple icons such as those used on the left hand side of Settings in iOS. Any advantage to using svg vs png?

Tags: xamarin.forms

I have icons built as svg or png just as easily.

Also for those people that are using svg, what's the method you are using to display these?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Official iOS Dev documentation says "the PNG format is the one most recommended for use in your apps". You can read it for a lot more information [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/2DDrawing/Conceptual/DrawingPrintingiOS/LoadingImages/LoadingImages.html).

although the supported file types table doesn't list .SVG. Apple values user experience. SVG scaling consumes a few more CPU cycles which they don't like. PNG rendering is more efficient than SVG,and there are cases like zoom-in / out scenarios where SVGs would be better though.

if you want to use SVG icons across platforms in Xamarin Forms,you could use the **Xamarin.FFImageLoading.Svg.Forms** library which allow us to achieve this easily.

the more you could refer to [SVG icons with FFImageLoading](https://www.xamboy.com/2018/03/29/sharing-svg-icons-across-platforms-in-xamarin-forms/)

Comment: +1 for FFImageLoading with SVG - this is what I am doing and it works very well. It is also my understanding that FFImageLoading brings other optimizations and improvements over a regular Image view- I would suggest even if you go with PNG files - you present them with FFImageLoading