# Xamarin.Forms: use SVG images as icons on a TabbedPage

Tags: xamarin.forms, uiimage

I want to use SVG images as icons on a `TabbedPage` in Xamarin.Forms for iOS.

The [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/navigation/tabbed-page) for the `TabbedPage` class provides the following tip:

> The `TabbedRenderer` for iOS has an overridable `GetIcon` method that can be used to load tab icons from a specified source. This override makes it possible to use SVG images as icons on a `TabbedPage`. In addition, selected and unselected versions of an icon can be provided.

I created the following class to perform the override:

```
[assembly: ExportRenderer(typeof(TabsRoot), typeof(TabbedPageCustomRenderer))]
namespace MyProject.iOS.Renderers
{
    public class TabbedPageCustomRenderer : TabbedRenderer
    {
        protected override Task<Tuple<UIImage, UIImage>> GetIcon(Page page)
        {
            var image = UIImage.FromFile(@"home-black-18dp.svg");
            return Task.FromResult(new Tuple<UIImage, UIImage>(image, image));
        }
    }
}
```

The accepted answer in [this](https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/179611/tabbed-page-with-svg-images) thread recommends creating a `UIImage` from an SVG file by doing something like this: `var myImage = UIImage.FromFile(<<file name>>)` where `<<filename>>` is an SVG. This [other thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32808901/svg-url-to-uiimage-ios) contradicts the previous thread, saying that `UIImages` cannot be made from SVG files. Sure enough, when I provide an SVG file, `UIImage.FromFile()` returns `null` and no icon is shown at all, just as the latter thread predicted. When I provide a PNG file, the override works as expected.

Another way I've tried to square this circle is to use the `SvgCachedImage` provided by `FFImageLoading.Svg.Forms`, but I haven't figured out how to 'wrap' a `UIImage` around an `SvgCachedImage` or whether that is even appropriate in this case.

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Add **Xamarin.FFImageLoading.Svg** nuget package to your ios project.

then create the `UImage` in your `GetIcon` method  like below :

```
UIImage img = await ImageService.Instance
    .LoadFile("timer.svg")
    .WithCustomDataResolver(new SvgDataResolver((int)(TabBar?.Bounds.Height / 2 ?? 30), (int)(TabBar?.Bounds.Height / 2 ?? 30), false))
    .AsUIImageAsync();
UIImage newImg = img.ImageWithRenderingMode(UIImageRenderingMode.AlwaysOriginal);
```

Comment: That's a really cool method for rasterizing an SVG input, but I'l like to display a true SVG without any pixelation / rasterization.

Comment: Maybe you could refer to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58906958/10768653).

Comment: Thanks. Do you mean to suggest that I should forego the SVG route and instead use rasterized icons? If so, do you know of a way to "scale" the rasterized graphics in my renderer above (i.e. increase dpi) so that there isn't any obvious pixelation in the displayed icons? My ultimate goal is to minimize pixelation; I'm less concerned about the particular image type, whether it's SVG, PNG, or something else. Thanks again for your help.

Comment: I think if you use the icon as tabbedpage icon,neither PNG nor SVG has much impact.